# How to prove that $e^{1/x} < \frac{1}{x} + 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I could reduce this problem to showing that there is no solution for $e^{1/x} = \frac{1}{x} + 1$ and both functions are continuous, but I am unable to prove the emptiness of the set of solutions either.

Comment: It's not true. For instance, if $x=\frac12$, it says $e^2<2+1$, which is false. Do you mean $x\in(1,\infty)$?

Comment: You can't prove it because is not true: if $x=1$ then $e^{1/x} = e \approx 2.73$ whereas $1/x+1 = 2$.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, my bad. It should really be $1 < x$.

Comment: You've got the inequality sign backwards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard by Maclaurin exp. that $e^y = 1+y \cdots > 1+y$. So put $y=1/x$ and reverse the inequality and then you'd be OK.

Comment: The reverse inequality is even true for negative $x$ too.

Answer (score 1):

To show the **reverse** inequality just set

- $\ln t = 1/x$ for $t > 1$

So, you get
$$t > \ln t + 1 \mbox{ for } t > 1$$
which follows immediately from $1-\frac{1}{t} > 0$ for $t>1$ and $1 = \ln 1 + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to prove "$>$". Replace $1/x \mapsto y$, recall your first lecture on Analysis and you're done.